# How to work with data values formatted [{}, {}, {}]

Tags: postgresql

I apologize if this is a simple question - I had some trouble even formatting the question when I was trying to Google for help!

In one of the tables I am working with, there's data value that looks like below:

| Invoice ID | Status | Product List |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Processed | [{"product_id":463153},{"product_id":463165},{"product_id":463177},{"pid":463218}] |

I want to count how many products each order has purchased. What is the proper syntax and way to count the values under "Product List" column? I'm aware that count() is wrong, and I need to maybe extract the data from the string value.

```
select invoice_id, count(Product_list) 

from quote_table

where status = 'processed'

group by invoice_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JSON` function named: `json_array_length` and cast this column like a `JSON` data type (as long as possible), for example:

```sql
select invoice_id, json_array_length(Product_list::json)  as count

from quote_table

where status = 'processed'

group by invoice_id;


 invoice_id | count 
------------+-------
     1234   |     4
(1 row)
```

Comment: It might of course already be json/jsonb type.

Comment: Thank you. However, using above, I am getting: ERROR: could not identify an equality operator for type json.

Comment: Actually, never mind I figured it out!